# Running .class file from cmd

Tags: java, cmd, console

[image]

Thats code:

```
package helloWorld;

public class helloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");

}

}
```

What's wrong? I am pretty newb.

Comment: Please tell us what is wrong.  What is the error message or exception message?  What is your current directory?  Where is the .class file?

Comment: rgettman, all these things can be clearly seen in the screenshots he has provided

Comment: @JPA ... which are blocked by my company.  Great.

Comment: C:\Users\jklh\Desktop\java_files\helloWorld\bin\helloWorld>java helloWorld   (thats what i type)   Could not find or load main class helloWorld (thats error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the classpath:

```
java -cp C:\Users\jklh\Desktop\java_files\helloWorld\bin helloWorld.helloWorld
```

Comment: Same error as before.

Comment: You have specified a package, try: java helloWorld.helloWorld